# How to fix embed code to display video cleanly/properly?

Tags: html, wordpress, video-streaming, embed

I am trying to embed a video onto my website but having difficulties with the standard embed code.

Here is a link to my webpage:

https://southhemitv.com/2019/07/08/test-jul-9-2019/

The standard embed code displays a very small video player with large black borders. Adding height="500" improves the size but then some extra features are added such as the chinese text at above the video.

I would like to hide this extra text so viewers only see the video and the player controls. (Edit) It has been suggested i store the video on my own server but i am not able to download certain videos and because its expensive most websites embed videos rather than store them on their server

If anyone could help it would be very appreciated.

The original embed code:

```
~<iframe src="//player.bilibili.com/player.html?aid=13125324&cid=21539921&page=1" scrolling="no" border="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" allowfullscreen="true"> </iframe>~
```

Link to original video:
https://www.bilibili.com/video/av13125324/

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download the video, then serve it from your own server or via CDN, use a videoplayer that you like and supports your video filetype.

The apparent issue here is the player's graphical interface.

Since you fetch the video from a website, it uses that website's video player (I think?).

In any case, just manually download the video & use the video player of your choice.